# How to Login in Jmeter on Java Script Popup

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter

How to login in Jmeter on Java script Popup, Popup is open on button click

Please help me step by step how to login Website for Load Testing.[image]

Comment: Please tell website name

Comment: http://demo.theupbeetkitchen.com/

Comment: You want to automate it through selenium ?

Comment: No Dear,  Client told me Load testing   by Jmeter, Is it possible dear for Jmeter

Comment: I can automate it through selenium. U tagged it with selenium. What you were testing?

Comment: ok , I will try , if any help full tips regarding for "automate selenium" for beginner please tell me  or send it URL Link which is helpful me for Load testing for Popup by the help of selenium.

Comment: Please Help me Mr. Kishan Patel..

Comment: You know how to run a testcase in eclipse ? for selenium ..

Comment: Yes Dear, Plz tell me steps.

Comment: You want code in JAVA for Login ?

Comment: yes dear , i have tested this website by using selenium webdriver...

Comment: I have posted my answer. See if it is working and reply me if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

To login in JMeter, see this link which will guide you step by step: [link](https://prelrik.wordpress.com/2016/05/03/basic-authentication-login-in-jmeter/)

I created a demo user account on your site and tested, It works fine. See below the result first has failed as it has no HTTP AUTHORIZATION MANAGER and seconds works after adding it.

[image: See the result]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get test script skeleton is recording the test.

Follow the next steps:

1. In JMeter:

   - File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create
   - Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder -> Start
2. In Browser:

   - Configure it to use:

     - proxy host: localhost
     - proxy port: 8888
     - use proxy for all protocols
     - not to bypass proxy for local addresses
3. Perform login in browser

JMeter should record the test. See [Apache JMeter proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) guide and [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) User Manual chapter if anything remains unclear.

I would also suggest adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) just in case website has checks for cookies and in general it is good to represent and maintain virtual user session.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and reply me if it is working or not:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://demo.theupbeetkitchen.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='customLogin']")).click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ID']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ID']")).sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
```